# how to decode the yjs binary data

Tags: typescript, y-websocket, yjs

I found the yjs have it's own protocol and communicate with binary data, now I want to print the text content of the message for debugging, I have read this issue https://discuss.yjs.dev/t/decoding-yjs-messages/264/4 and found the `Y.logUpdateV2(data);` from here https://docs.yjs.dev/api/document-updates, so I log the plain text on the text like this:

```
wsProvider.on('message', (event: MessageEvent) => {
        const data: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(event.data);
        Y.logUpdateV2(data);
    });
```

but the code shows error:

```
decoding.js:103 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 17656330
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at readUint8Array (decoding.js:103:16)
    at readVarUint8Array (decoding.js:118:45)
    at new UpdateDecoderV2 (UpdateDecoder.js:175:72)
    at Module.logUpdateV2 (updates.js:126:25)
    at CollarEditorService.ts?t=1698578910264:98:7
    at observable.js:154:90
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider.emit (observable.js:154:77)
    at websocket.onmessage (y-websocket.js:144:16)
```

is it possible to fixed this issue? what should I do to output the plain text of yjs? I also tried the `Y.logUpdate(data);`, still could not work.